# Can someone help me fix the end statement of this rock paper scissors game i m trying to create

Tags: python, if-statement, debugging

```html
import random


rock = '''
    _______
---'   ____)
      (_____)
      (_____)
      (____)
---.__(___)
'''

paper = '''
    _______
---'   ____)____
          ______)
          _______)
         _______)
---.__________)
'''

scissors = '''
    _______
---'   ____)____
          ______)
       __________)
      (____)
---.__(___)
'''
anci = [rock,paper,scissors]

Opponent_choice = int(input("What do you choose? Type 0 for Rock, 1 for Paper, 2 for Scissors\n"))

print(anci[Opponent_choice])
# ------------------------------------
Comp_choice = random.randint(0,2)
Comp_choice_alt = anci[Comp_choice] 

print(f"Computer chose: {Comp_choice} \n {Comp_choice_alt}")

if Opponent_choice==0&Comp_choice == 0:
  print("It's a draw")
elif Opponent_choice == 0 & Comp_choice == 1:
  print("You lose")
elif Opponent_choice == 0&Comp_choice == 2:
  print("You win")
elif Opponent_choice == 1&Comp_choice == 0:
  print("You win")
elif Opponent_choice==1&Comp_choice == 1:
  print("It's a draw")
elif Opponent_choice == 1&Comp_choice == 2:
  print("You lose")
elif Opponent_choice == 2&Comp_choice == 0:
  print("You lose")
elif Opponent_choice == 2&Comp_choice == 1:
  print("You win")
elif Opponent_choice==2&Comp_choice == 2:
  print("It's a draw")
```

Its not showing "You win" or "You lose" at times unlike how it is supposed to it's showing "It's A Draw" where it is supposed to print "You win"

I think there's something wrong with my if-else statements.

Comment: Can you be more precise than "at certain times"?  And please post code as text in the question, not a link to text.

Comment: Please post a [mre] here, not a link to a remote site.

Comment: Don't use `&` where you mean `and`. They are not equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

Change all of your single & to 'and' see code.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-and-and-in-python/

```
if Opponent_choice ==  0 and Comp_choice == 0:
  print("It's a draw")
elif Opponent_choice == 0 and Comp_choice == 1:
  print("You lose")
elif Opponent_choice == 0 and Comp_choice == 2:
  print("You win")
elif Opponent_choice == 1 and Comp_choice == 0:
  print("You win")
elif Opponent_choice == 1 and Comp_choice == 1:
  print("It's a draw")
elif Opponent_choice == 1 and Comp_choice == 2:
  print("You lose")
elif Opponent_choice == 2 and Comp_choice == 0:
  print("You lose")
elif Opponent_choice == 2 and Comp_choice == 1:
  print("You win")
elif Opponent_choice == 2 and Comp_choice == 2:
  print("It's a draw")
```

Answer (score 1):

Should use `and` not `&`. Here is an article that explains why

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-and-and-in-python/

```
  if Opponent_choice==0 and Comp_choice == 0:
    print("It's a draw")
  elif Opponent_choice == 0 and Comp_choice == 1:
    print("You lose")
  elif Opponent_choice == 0 and Comp_choice == 2:
    print("You win")
  elif Opponent_choice == 1 and Comp_choice == 0:
    print("You win")
  elif Opponent_choice==1 and Comp_choice == 1:
    print("It's a draw")
  elif Opponent_choice == 1 and Comp_choice == 2:
    print("You lose")
  elif Opponent_choice == 2 and Comp_choice == 0:
    print("You lose")
  elif Opponent_choice == 2 and Comp_choice == 1:
    print("You win")
  elif Opponent_choice==2 and Comp_choice == 2:
    print("It's a draw")
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides using `and`, you can simplify your conditional logic

```
if Opponent_choice == Comp_choice:
    print("It's a draw")
elif (
    (Opponent_choice == 0 and Comp_choice == 1)
    or (Opponent_choice == 1 and Comp_choice == 2)
    or (Opponent_choice == 2 and Comp_choice == 0)
):
    print('You lose')
else:
    print('You win')
```